# Window Azure solution- Not running under local solution

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

need urgent help 
i am not able to run the solution in the local environment. I have created the hello world sample and trying to run the application but i am getting error like some prerequisites are missing. Below in the configuration i have.

Installed in VM--
Window server 2008 OS-32 Bit
VS 2010
Installed the Azure SDK

But when i am running the solution i am getting below error ---
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: The Windows Azure development fabric and development storage are running on a 32-bit workstation. In the cloud, Windows Azure Hosted Services run in a 64-bit environment. The use of native code execution or .Net Full Trust features such as P/Invoke may require migration to 64-bit. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=145047 for details.
Windows Azure Tools: Error: Running .NET 4.0 web roles on the Windows Azure Development Fabric requires installing the following QFE: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958854, or upgrading to SP2 of Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008.
Windows Azure Tools: The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service. Please see the release notes.

Can any one suggest what i am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

As said, you are using 32-bit environment. Retry on 64-bit Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure the client profile in not set on the .NET Assembly versioning... Choose .NET 4

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade to SP2 of Windows Server 2008 as suggested by the warning message ? And the mentioned hotfix for IIS7 & .NET 4.0: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958854.